# Data Structure for managing groups in a chat server

Tags: c, linux, data-structures

I have a chat client in flash using binary sockets and a server in C/linux using sockets and libev. I have everything working properly for sending and receiving messages but now I am on to the more complicated step.

For my chat server I will be grouping users into groups of 15. The server will need to have a unique ID for each user and be able to quickly determine which group a user is in to broadcast the message to the other 14 users. I'm thinking the server could use the file descriptor for each socket connection as those should all be unique.

**The problem is this:** you get a read event fired from libev for a certain file descriptor. You now need to quickly determine which group this FD belongs to and then broadcast the message to everyone in the group. *What is the best data structure for this problem?*

Answer (score 1):

HashTable.
Have each user have a groupID associated with it and the hashTable will use groupIDs as keys and arrays of UserIDs as values.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. When using libev I don't believe I have any control over the parameters being passed into a read event. The ev_io struct is all I have to work with, which has an int for the FD and that is about it. I think you are on to something though, I'm going to try to think of a way around this.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to hash once on the FD to find the groupID and then hash again on the groupID to find the array of userID's. Having two hash tables and the computation of two hashes may be a killer though.

Comment: If you think that two hash table lookups are going to be what makes your performance unacceptable, when doing I/O over network sockets, there's something seriously weird with your setup. How many simultaneous users are you dimensioning this for? Hundreds of thousands?